# Export to new workbook

Tags: excel, export

When i use this code i get save as window and save workbook as i whish, but i also get one more workbook with active sheet from original, need help to get just one and if it is possible to close it after saving.

Code

```
Sub WorksheetSaveToNewWorkbook()
    Dim loc As Variant
    Dim Rng     As Range
    Dim newName As String
    Dim newWkb  As Workbook
    Dim newWks  As Worksheet
    Dim Wks     As Worksheet
    Dim Shp     As Shape
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set Wks = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Set Rng = Wks.Range("Q3:S170")
        
        Data = Range("Q3:S170")
        
        Wks.Copy
        Set newWkb = Workbooks.Add
        Set newWks = newWkb.ActiveSheet
        
        With newWks
            .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
            newName = " inklinometrija" & ".xlsx"
            
            For Each Shp In .Shapes
                Shp.OnAction = ""
            Next Shp
            
    loc = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Save As...", InitialFileName:=newName)
    If loc <> False Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=loc, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Wks.Copy
Set newWkb = Workbooks.Add
Set newWks = newWkb.ActiveSheet
```

`Wks.copy` is in fact the code to create a new workbook with just that worksheet.

Comment: Tnx a lot :) works now. Just to figure out how to close it after save :) * done that to tnx for help